# How do i move the camera for my 2D game?

Tags: java

I tried looking into tutorials on how to do that but i always get confused because they have a lot of code that they don't explain well. I want to understand what everything does so.. What is the simplest way to have a camera which moves as the player hits the right arrow button.

Comment: That question is way too broad for SO. You have not specified what you have done so far, how your game (engine) is implemented or even what you have tried to do. Simply moving a camera would mean that you modify its `x` and `y` values, but the exact code is highly implementation dependant (e.g.: how your camera is implemented and how you are rendering)

Comment: @UnholySheep Well i try to keep the game simple so i dont have a rendering system. My code is pretty much a mess since im not very experienced. I just want to have a zoomed version of a level and it will move (Show more things) on the right side.

Comment: If you don't have a rendering system then how are you displaying anything on screen? and once again - the exact code would depend on how your game is displaying graphics. Basically you just want to listen to keypresses and modify your camera's value (position) based on that.

Comment: You don't have a rendering system? So how do you display the game? If you're a beginner, you should look into basic game engine programming (with java e.g. with LWJGL, OpenGL etc.), then you'll see for yourself how cameras in games work.

Comment: @UnholySheep I set the  layout of the panel to null and i use setLocation(x,y) to place things in the game

Comment: Panel? what panel? are you using swing or javafx or something along those lines? if yes, these GUI frameworks are not particularly well suited for creating games

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you have to understand the difference between model space, world space and view space and translate between these separate coordinate systems.

Create a class called Camera that has x and y coordinates - or better yet, a camera matrix (projection and world matrices combined).

Create an Entity class that represents your game objects. They should have x and y coordinates, and perhaps an angle - or better still, a world matrix.

Create another class called something like SceneGraph that's basically a spatial container that allows you to store entities by their coordinates and query which entities are within some bounding rectangle.

Your render loop would then go as follows:

- Query the scene graph to find the entities that are within view of the camera.
- For each entity, translate its world coordinates into view space (screen coordinates) and render it.